# linq .Any with list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table that looks like this:

```
UserID | FruitID
  4    |    34
  4    |   4355
  4    |   652
  5    |   5677
  5    |    562
  4    |    562
```

For now, I'm passing a UserID and a FruitID like this:

```
var IsAuthorized = MyDC.FruitTable
                       .Any(f => f.UserID == TheUserID && 
                                 f.FruitID == TheFruitID);
```

This returns a boolean. Now I want to write the same thing for a list of FruitID: I pass in a UserID and a several FruitIDs and I want a boolean that says `"ALL the FruitIDs have a UserID == to the TheUserID"`.

> *Note that if a list contains just one element that doesn't match
> FruitID == f.FruitID && f.UserID == UserID then the return should be
> false for the entire list.*

How do I rewrite my query to take in a list of FruitIDs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leaving the fact that your sample code wouldn't compile, I suspect you want something like:

```
// Here fruitIDs is a List<int> for the "target" fruit IDs
var isAuthorized = MyDC.FruitTable
                       .Where(u => fruitIDs.Contains(u.FruitID))
                       .All(u => u.UserID == TheUserID);
```

This will check that every entry such that the fruit ID is in the given list *also* matches the specified user ID. There are alternative ways of writing it, of course.

It *doesn't* check that every entry in the original collection has a valid fruit ID. It's not clear from the question whether that was the aim or not...

Comment: Thanks: yes, the aim is to check that EVERY entry in the FruitID parameter list has a corresponding UserID.

Comment: @frenchie: That's not what you wrote in the question... it's basically hard to understand *exactly* what you want. If you'd provide sample inputs and expected outputs, it would make it considerably simpler to understand.

Comment: I wrote "ALL the FruitIDs have a UserID == to the TheUserID". Note that if a list contains just one element that doesn't match FruitID == UserID then the return should be false for the entire list" and I thought that was descriptive enough; apologies if it was not clear.

Comment: @frenchie: But FruitID isn't going to match UserID for anything; I would expect you to match a FruitID in the actual data with a FruitID in the input data, and then match the corresponding user ID with the single target user ID. Your question is *still* unclear. The "FruitID == UserID" expression that you've used in multiple places really isn't helpful.

Comment: ok, got it; no FruitID and UserID don't have to match; just that every record that has f.FruitID == "a FruitID from the list" && f.UserID == TheUserID.

Comment: @frenchie: Right - which is exactly what my answer gives, more by luck than anything else given the lack of clarity of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use listVariable.Contains(...)

```
        MyDC.FruitTable
                   .Where(x => x.UserID == TheUserID)
                   .All(x => listOfFruitIds.Contains(x.FruitID));
```